# Enconding .rmd file mac

Tags: r, macos, encoding, r-markdown

Yesterday I was doing an RMD file with a Mac and everything went well, but today, when I reopened the file it looks like this:

> D??Pˆ@A????DE????UOØÊË?? Z†é¡*Áç€????Z[??¯íñ»•??`@??A??xE??eE*??ç@????
>   f=T??ž Ë^??‚??l[iótó:ò??§FÌ????w72??øø‡ˆDA????U??@?? N??¯??J‡??E????NO´Á??€í??Ç_žË??S|V1™??;¯??îR‘”xe^gP??‹@K??????tO9¢??ì|£æ8??????i;v??7Z??§¬ç˜??/‰RM’ÂmŽlwi3vÇ7œ¡ÊAç????ZE????êJøÀ‡??E??D??AQ??Œ^aD????A[??ô…b›N?????óò†^ƒ®«??Èq??%Z§??Ë®????r#,æ????D??}Q¾ Tçœ??BQ??Œ,^Ž®t??;~??Z†hƒrá/??‡¨EŒ??]Iì«ÁÈ????SO‘Êyç??{~]ë??KôüÍ????nd#Xèñü•??amGo??akG{??jW}—(Ÿ˜
>   ,??Ø&ï¿&ïbN??qô$…òš??6€¦??áY??Í¬??˜,(˜r-,”f}U?? Ë??_å??(Z–??$€ò??§^Ì®????3rÇ/œˆ@E????N??Aô??Í??^€??KQÈŒ??]QìŠÊ[ç¯??î^}??+Dž??\Wƒ??«#üƒ??µoÀa??E??9D????q['ò????‰®N??¤}î*|??
>   :????B[??ô,…š~5????Y…T›œ

Does someone know how to revert the encoding?

Comment: Pull the latest good version from git (or whatever source control tool you are using). If you're not using a source control system, then go back through your Time Machine backups and pull the last good version from there.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a Windows user, I have an easy way to make a corrupted file readable: you can reopen the file with whatever encoding you want. First of all, open the file as usual. Then, if you see the file garbled, click `File` and `Reopen with Encoding...` button, as shown in the following picture.

[image]

`Choose Encoding` will appear next, so you can choose one.

[image]